# Find the value of $x$ that satisfy the equation: $3^{11}+3^{11}+3^{11} = 3^x$

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-sum

I have this question:

> > $$3^{11}+3^{11}+3^{11} = 3^x$$
> >     Find the value of $x$

Comment: $3^{11}+3^{11}+3^{11}=3^{12}$ and the exponential is injective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Takking $3^{11}$ common from left hand side,

$3^{11}(1 + 1 + 1) = 3^x$

$3^{11}(3) = 3^x$

$3^{12} = 3^x$

$x = 12$

> Or -

$3(3^{11})= 3^x$

$3^{12} = 3^x$

$x = 12$

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

> > $$3^{11}+3^{11}+3^{11} = 3^x\implies 3^{10}(3^{1} + 3^{1} + 3^{1}) =3^x$$
> >     $$(3^1 + 3^1+ 3^1) = \frac {3^x} {3^{10}}$$
> >     $$9 = \frac{3^x}{3^{10}}$$
> >     $$3^2 = \frac {3^x}{3^{10}}$$
> >     **Hence**:
> >     $$2 = x -10$$
> >     $$x = 12$$

Comment: Ah, one of those self-answered questions?

Comment: Yes, it was meant to be shared ;)

Comment: Its good you solved it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

More simply:

$$3^{11}+3^{11}+3^{11}=3\times 3^{11}=3^{12}$$

so the answer you are looking for is $x=12$ (because $x\mapsto 3^x$ is injective).